# Retrieve data from WCF to store on SQL Server CE (TableAdapter)

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-ce, tableadapter

I have a Compact Framework 2.0 app that consume a WCF service. The data that retrieve from the service will be store on a SQL Server 2005 CE.

The SQL Server CE database has his own tables. I use a TableAdapter to access SQL Server CE and Insert and Select statement to store and retrieve data.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are there problems with how you're doing it now? In general, the answer to the question "is there a better way to do it" is "it depends". There's nothing obvious wrong with what you're doing, so a true answer will depend on the details you have not supplied in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider sync framework

http://blogs.msdn.com/sync/archive/2009/06/04/announcing-sync-framework-2-0-ctp2.aspx